# Spring / Hazelcast / Kubernetes : Node failed to start when running two pods silmultaneously

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, hazelcast

##### Context

I am trying to set up Hazelcast for a Spring Boot API running in Kubernetes. This API is running in two pods that need to be able to communicate.

##### Configuration

I have the following Hazelcast Java configuration defined :

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
  <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
Config config = getCommonConfig();
JoinConfig joinConfig = config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin();
joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getKubernetesConfig().setEnabled(true)
        .setProperty("namespace", namespace)
        .setProperty("service-name", service);
```

##### Description of the problem

When running only one pod the API is running without any error.

When I scale my application with `kubectl scale deployment <deployment_name> --replicas=2`, the second pod fails with the following stack trace :

```
WARN ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization 
cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastInstance' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/hazelcast/HazelcastServerConfiguration$HazelcastServerConfigConfiguration.class]:
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]:
Factory method 'hazelcastInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node failed to start!
```

This stack is very obscure and setting the `LOG_LEVEL` to `DEBUG` does not add any additional log.

It seems that the following `@Bean` defined in `HazelcastServerConfiguration` fails to instantiate when I have two pods running even though it runs fine when I only have one.

```java
@Configuration(
    proxyBeanMethods = false
)
@ConditionalOnSingleCandidate(Config.class)
static class HazelcastServerConfigConfiguration {
    HazelcastServerConfigConfiguration() {
    }

    @Bean
    HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance(Config config) {
        return HazelcastServerConfiguration.getHazelcastInstance(config);
    }
}
```

I tried :

- Using `hazelcast-kubernetes` in addition of `hazelcast`, exact same problem happened.
- Running in `LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG` to have more information, nothing more was logged.

##### Kubernetes configuration

**service.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: FOO
  [...]
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
    - port: 5701
      protocol: TCP
      name: hazelcast
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: FOO
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: BAR
```

**deployment.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: FOO
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: FOO
    [...]
spec:
  replicas: 2
  [...]
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
            - name: hazelcast
              containerPort: 5701
              protocol: TCP
```

Comment: Please show the kubernetes manifests

Comment: @Thomas I added the `service.yaml` and `deployment.yaml` kubernetes files in the question.